# useCustomHook being called on every render - is something wrong with this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a `useCustomHook` that I use in various components. I have simplified it for the purposes of this example

It looks like this:

```
export const useCustomHook = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  const doSomething = () => {
       ...do stuff here
  }

  return {
    items,
    setItems,
    doSomething
  };
};
```

I am then using it throughout various components.

```
const App = () => {
   const { items, setItems, doSomething } = useCustomHook();

   return <div>whatever</div>
}
```

When this component gets re-rendered I can see that the `useCustomHook` gets recalled. The behavior works as expected but I am wondering if this is the correct usage of a custom hook and if there is something I can/should do to prevent the hook being recalled on every render.

Comment: Are you running into a particular problem with the hook being run again?

Comment: That is how hooks work, they are called every render in the same order they are defined. Is there any specific issue you have with it running each render?

Comment: i think it still depends on what you mean by `run again`. If you put console.log inside this `useCustomHook`, yes it's run again. But in your code, not everything is. For instance, `[]` the initial value isn't passed in again. If you use `useCallback` or `useMemo` you'll also see certain things not run again.

Comment: Not exactly a problem, but noticed that it keeps getting invoked, but everything is behaving as expected. @CertainPerformance

Comment: @windmaomao i did look at using useCallback or useMemo but was seeing that you can't use a hook inside these.

Comment: @DrewReese no real issue, but was just curious as to whether the way i was using it is bad practice. But as you say this is how they work. So the same state etc is maintained and duplicate states are not created, i guess based on how react works under the hood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your custom hook's body runs again every time there's a re-render is completely normal and should not pose a problem in most cases.

Two cases where it *could* be an issue would be:

- if something it returns is used elsewhere, and you want to keep the return value as static as possible to avoid *other* re-renders
- if something your hook does in its body is an expensive computation

Both be fixed by memoizing the values returned whenever possible. For example, `doSomething` could be changed to:

```
  const doSomething = useCallback(() => {
       ...do stuff here
  }, [ /* dependency array */ ]);
```

so that its reference only changes when necessary - when the dependency array changes.

State setter functions references are already static, so that's not something to worry about with `setItems`.

If you're doing something expensive in the hook body, memoize it. Change

```
export const useCustomHook = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  const doSomething = () => {
       ...do stuff here
  }
  const expensiveValue = compute(items);

  return {
    items,
    setItems,
    doSomething,
    expensiveValue
  };
};
```

to

```
export const useCustomHook = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  const doSomething = () => {
       ...do stuff here
  }
  const expensiveValue = useMemo(() => compute(items), [items]);

  return {
    items,
    setItems,
    doSomething,
    expensiveValue
  };
};
```