# React Custom Hook function keeps recalling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to the thread below,

[useCustomHook being called on every render - is something wrong with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67612297/usecustomhook-being-called-on-every-render-is-something-wrong-with-this)

It says it is completely normal to keep calling the custom hook function every time React re-renders.

My questions are, if it affects on a performance side when returning an array from this Custom Hook function( Not when fetching API and receiving data ) which contains a lot of values.

If so, how to prevent it ( How to let this Custom Hook function run only once )?

Here is my Custom Hook code, it returns an array which contains around 5000 string values.

```
function FetchWords(url: string) {
  const [data, setData] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((words) => words.text())
      .then((textedWords) => {
        setData(textedWords.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split("\n"));
      });
  }, []);
  const expensiveData = useMemo(() => data, [data]);
  return expensiveData;
}

export default FetchWords;
```

My Main js

```
const wordLists: any[] = useFetch(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/charlesreid1/five-letter-words/master/sgb-words.txt"
  );
```

Comment: What version of React are you using?

Comment: Custom hooks should start with the word `use` and `useMemo` here makes no sense. Since you're fetching the data only on mount, performance should be fine, because on subsequent renders the data would not be fetched, it would just be returned from the hook.

Comment: @StaffordRose I am using "react": "^18.1.0"

Comment: @StaffordRose How does the React version matter here?

Comment: @SSM Oh, I will modify the name, and yes. I used useMemo just to see different cases. So for the performance side, though it would be fine, wouldn't it be better to not return any values & keep reassigning to a variable? if the values are way too big?

Comment: Follow this issue for React 18 double rendering. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24502 , its actually an upgrade than a bug.

Comment: @SSM See niko's comment

Comment: @niko Oh I know it will be double rendering since React.Strict was added in the index.tsx , my concern is just about returning values which if it may affects performance side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. CustomHooks should start with word `use...`
2. You don't need `useMemo` in your hook, simply return `data` state.
3. Your hook makes the `fetch` call only once, so no problem there as the effect has empty dependency, so it runs once after first render.
4. The hook stores the array of 5000 entries once in `data` state and returns the same reference each time your custom hook is called during component re-renders. There is no copy operation, so you don't need to worry about that.
5. If you only want to `fetch` 100 entries for example, then your backend needs to provide that api.

Hope this resolves your queries as it is not very clear what is your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are worried about bringing all this data at the same time, you can indicate from the backend that they send you a certain number of records and from the frontend you can manage them with the pagination.
2. the use of useMemo is superfluous.
3. the useEffect that you are using will only be rendered ONCE, that is, it will only call the 5,000 registers that you mention only once

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But my question was if the return value of Custom Hook is too big which may be a problem for performance side. I should have written the question more clearly. Sorry :<